# Partitioned Existing table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which is 800 GB and I need to partition it by year

This is a current table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MessageInbox]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [Subject] [VARCHAR](250) NULL,
    [MessageFrom] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [MessageText] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [DateReceived] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [ProfileId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [IsRead] [BIT] NULL,
    [InstanceId] [INT] NULL,
    [msgType] [VARCHAR](25) NULL,
    [Tags] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [excerpt] [VARCHAR](500) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Inbox]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
             ) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY];
GO
```

This is how I though in partitioning

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [PartitioningByYear] (DATETIME)
AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES
(   '20150101',
    '20160101',
    '20170101',
    '20180101',
    '20190101',
    '20200101',
    '20210101',
    '20220101',
    '20230101',
    '20240101'
);


---DROP PARTITION FUNCTION [PartitioningByYear];
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME PartitionByYear
AS PARTITION PartitioningByYear
TO
(
    Year2014,
    Year2015,
    Year2016,
    Year2017,
    Year2018,
    Year2019,
    Year2020,
    Year2021,
    Year2022,
    Year2023,
    Year2024
);


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MessageInbox]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [Subject] [VARCHAR](250) NULL,
    [MessageFrom] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [MessageText] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [DateReceived] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [ProfileId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [IsRead] [BIT] NULL,
    [InstanceId] [INT] NULL,
    [msgType] [VARCHAR](25) NULL,
    [Tags] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [excerpt] [VARCHAR](500) NULL
) ON PartitionByYear (DateCreated);

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX CI_MessageInbox1
ON dbo.MessageInbox (DateCreated);
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_messageinbox_id ON dbo.MessageInbox (Id);
```

My questions are

1- Is this the optimal way to create the partition  table ?

2- I am confused in not having the ID as primary key , is there a way to add it to primary key?

3- Having the datecreated as the key in the clustered index. isn't this will degrade the performance and will add extra key lookups for every query?

I want to partition the table since I though it will be easier if I need to archive / drop older years. And I can create index / maintain on partitions instead of have one index on the whole table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The primary key doesn't need to be the same as the clustering key.  The default when creating a primary key is to also make it the clustered index, but that isn't *required*.

Try this for the `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MessageInbox]
(
    [Id] [INT] NOT NULL
        IDENTITY(1, 1)
        NOT FOR REPLICATION
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
    [Subject] [VARCHAR](250) NULL,
    [MessageFrom] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [MessageText] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [DateReceived] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
        INDEX MessageInbox_cx CLUSTERED,
    [ProfileId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [IsRead] [BIT] NULL,
    [InstanceId] [INT] NULL,
    [msgType] [VARCHAR](25) NULL,
    [Tags] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [excerpt] [VARCHAR](500) NULL
) ON PartitionByYear (DateCreated);
```

That will make the `[id]` column the primary key, and the `[DateCreated]` column will be the clustered index.

Without knowing very much about your data, I'd say it would probably be helpful to add data compression to your table and non-clustered indexes.  You can do that by adding the following to the `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MessageInbox]
(
    [Id] [INT] NOT NULL
        IDENTITY(1, 1)
        NOT FOR REPLICATION
        PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
        WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE),
    [Subject] [VARCHAR](250) NULL,
    [MessageFrom] [VARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [MessageText] [VARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [DateReceived] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
        INDEX MessageInbox_cx CLUSTERED
        WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE),
    [ProfileId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [IsRead] [BIT] NULL,
    [InstanceId] [INT] NULL,
    [msgType] [VARCHAR](25) NULL,
    [Tags] [VARCHAR](100) NULL,
    [excerpt] [VARCHAR](500) NULL
) ON PartitionByYear (DateCreated);
```

Comment: I got this error while creating the table 

Msg 1908, Level 16, State 1, Line 219

Column 'DateCreated' is partitioning column of the index 'PK__MessageInbox__0C403E8D'. Partition columns for a unique index must be a subset of the index key.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 219
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

Comment: to make it work , I add this CONSTRAINT PK_MessageInbox PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (ID,DateCreated) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)  at the end instead of PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED
        WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE),